# Notification request not showing up issue

Tags: javascript, .net, push-notification, notifications

I'm developing a web application (.NET Framework 4.8). The user is supposed to fill a form in and after the button **Add** is clicked, a notification should pop-up on all devices, where notifications are permitted.

By default the browser should ask for notifications permission and the user should see an alert-type note to either accept, or reject them. However, I cannot create this notification request. If I allow notifications from this website, the notification is displayed, but I don't want to force the user to go through the browser's settings.

Here's my attempt at doing it. Basically, I first ask if the browser supports notifications. If it does, I ask whether permission is granted. In case it is, the notification is displayed. If not, a notification request should pop up. However, that's not the case and the compiler just carries on. Here's my Java Script function:

```
/* Java Script */
function notifyMe() {
  var notify = new Notification('My title', {
    body: 'This is the body of the notification.',
    badge: '/Content/badge.png',
    icon: '/Content/icon.png'
  });
  if (!window.Notification) {
    alert('This browser does not support notifications!');
  }
  else {
    alert('Notification is created. Will it get displayed?');
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      note.showNotification(notify);
    }
    else {
      alert('We are going to ask for permission!');
      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        alert('Asking right now!');
        if (permission === 'granted') {
          alert('Notification is coming!');
          note.showNotification(notify);
        }
        else {
          alert('User blocked notifications.');
        }
        alert('By now we must have already been asked!');
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the HTML of the button, which when clicked on, calls the function:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="notifyMe()" value="Add"/>
```

I am rather new to Java Script, so my code snippet is inspired by these three sites: [1](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-show-notifications-in-javascript), [2](https://hackernoon.com/display-desktop-notifications-using-javascript), [3](https://web.dev/push-notifications-display-a-notification/). I couldn't find anything relevant on stackoverflow, but I might have missed something.
As I said earlier, I want this notification to be displayed to everyone, who has accepted notifications on their device, but I think this function will send a notification only to the device, on which the form is filled in. Is this the case?

**Summary:**
I have two questions:
Why does my code not send notification requests and how to fix this?
Can multi-device notifications be sent with this function?

Thanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit:** I added the `manifest.json` file, suggested in the commetns of the answer, but it seems to have done nothing. For the sake of clarity, I added some more `alert`-s here and there (check the code again). What I observe, are the following notifications:

```
Notification is created. Will it get displayed?
We are going to ask for permission!
```

And then I'm redirtected to another page, accoring to the button's event handler. I don't even see `Asking right now!`, which suggests that the line

```
Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) =>
```

is not executed properly. I'm not sure whether or not this inforamtion can be of any use, but I'm still sharing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange order of things and can use another try/catch.

Have a go with this

```js
function notifyMe() {
  if (!window.Notification) {
    alert('This browser does not support notifications!');
    return
  }
  try {
    var notify = new Notification('My title', {
      body: 'This is the body of the notification.',
      badge: '/Content/badge.png',
      icon: '/Content/icon.png'
    });
    if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
      note.showNotification(notify);
    } else {
      Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
        if (permission === 'granted') {
          note.showNotification(notify);
        } else {
          alert('User blocked notifications.');
        }
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, your solution does the same - if I manually allow notifications, a notification is displayed. If it is set to Ask, I don't get a notification permision request.

Comment: Here is someone who say that adding a manifest helped: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/725772?answerId=746678022#746678022